# Почему std::aligned_storage является deprecated начиная с c++23?

Tags: c++

Почему `std::aligned_storage` является **deprecated** начиная с **c++23**?

Мне также интересно, что нужно будет использовать вместо `std::aligned_storage`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828288/why-is-stdaligned-storage-to-be-deprecated-in-c23-and-what-to-use-instead

Comment: Хотя по ссылке написано, что "его использование вызывает UB", мне так и [не смогли объяснить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72159147/2752075), где конкретно там UB.